# Is it safe to use O_DIRECT without O_SYNC?

Tags: linux, io, filesystems, linux-device-driver

I have a linux application that streams data to files on a directly-attached SAS storage array. It fills large buffers, writes them in O_DIRECT mode, then recycles the buffers (i.e. fills them again etc.). I do not need to use O_SYNC for data integrity, because I can live with data loss on crashes, delayed writing etc. I'm primarily interested in high throughput and I seem to get better performance without O_SYNC. However, I am wondering if it is safe: if O_DIRECT is used but not O_SYNC, when exactly does the write() system call return?

- If the write() returns after the DMA to the storage array's cache has been completed, then my application is safe to fill the buffer again. The array itself is in write-back mode: it will write to disk eventually, which is acceptable to me.
- If the write returns immediately after the DMA has been initiated (but not yet completed), then my application is not safe, because it would overwrite the buffer while the DMA is still in progress. Obviously I don't want to write corrupted data; but in this case there is also no way that I know to figure out when the DMA for a buffer has been completed and it is safe to refill.

(There are actually several parallel threads, each one with its pool of buffers, although this may not really matter for the question above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the write call returns you can reuse the buffer without any danger. You don't know that the write has made it to disk, but you indicated that was not an issue for you.

One supporting reference is at http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-3, which states:

> For example, the use of direct I/O requires that the write system call
>   operate synchronously; otherwise the application does not know when it
>   can reuse its I/O buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know then what difference does the O_SYNC make when O_DIRECT is used? Because it looks like with or without O_SYNC, the write() returns only when the buffer has been transferred to the storage array's cache. (The array is in write-back mode, so it signals completion as soon as all the data is in its cache.) Yet without O_SYNC I do see a ~30% improvement in throughput for both ext4 and xfs, with the array's configuration unchanged.

Comment: O_DIRECT is only advertised to minimise or eliminate caching by the OS, so I suppose there might be some cache data flushed when you use O_SYNC with O_DIRECT. Also, O_SYNC will force metadata for the file to be flushed, which will reduce performance.

Comment: `O_DIRECT` means you will bypass the Linux operating system page cache but even when the write has completed you do not know whether the data is still in a volatile cache belonging to the disk (i.e. you know the "disk" has the data but you do not know if it is on stable media that will survive power loss). To know that the write is on non-volatile media you need to use the `O_SYNC` flag (on Linux) or the `fsync()` function. See http://serverfault.com/a/585427/303019 for why there was a speed difference.